# How do I import data from one database to another using script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a database *DocData* size with 8 GB. I want to move three tables form *DocData* to another database *DocData2* with out using import export wizard and
identity columns in these tables. I want to move it using a script and copy data with identity column. One of the tables size is 7 GB.

I am using this query

```
CREATE TABLE [DocData2].[dbo].DocumentPages AS 
SELECT  * FROM [DocData].[dbo].[DocumentPages]
```

but I am getting the following error.

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FROM BOL

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . ] table  ON
```

do inserts here

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . ] table  OFF
```

Comment: That's not at all what that statement does.

Comment: @JohnN Please explain why that is incorrect.   The problem statement includes Identity columns.   If there are any gaps in the Identity value then that is how to handle that.  +1

Comment: So it does, I completely missed that in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run the following statement.

*Assumptions*:

- Both your databases exist on the same server.
- Your destination table `DocumentPages` doesn't already exist in your destination database `DocData2`

*Script*:

```
SELECT  *   
INTO    [DocData2].[dbo].[DocumentPages] 
FROM    [DocData].[dbo].[DocumentPages]
```

*Your Issue*:

You cannot create tables using the script in the question. [**CREATE TABLE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258255%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) doesn't have any option to accept SELECT output to create a new table in such manner.

Answer (score 3):

Please use this script.

```
SELECT * INTO [DocData2].[dbo].DocumentPages FROM [DocData].[dbo].[DocumentPages]
```

[***Read here to know more about SELECT INTO***](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/select-into/).

Comment: Frankly this is a poor choice because it will not create indexes or other constraints other than the identity.

Answer (score 0):

you can only do that if both databases are on the same server. If they are on different servers you need to use other techniques like Linked server or SSIS packages.

That being said, you need to first create your [DocData2].[dbo].DocumentPages table and then copy the data from one table to another

```
insert into [DocData2].[dbo].[DocumentPages]
select * from  [DocData].[dbo].[DocumentPages]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an exact copy, then script the table (right click on the table in the object brwoser, you will see the option to create a script) and all of its indexes, constraints etc. (you may need to script teh indexes separately) then create the  table by running the script then write an insert statement like the one @Diego did (only specifying columns, inserts shoudl alawys specify columns).

Of course if you were managing your database corectly, you would already have the script in source control. At least start to do this now with these scripts.